# how to Extract the data from http://www.pse.com.ph/servlet/TickerServletFile save into mysql database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This should be a code igniter based class,

The table header should be

Price   Percent_change Company Name  Company Code   Volume

Please help any one knows?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to parse the file and insert it into a database. A quick look at the link shows that it seems to be all separated by semi-colons. Take a look at [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

To get your results, simply do

```
$splitContents = explode($rawContents);
$counter=0
while($counter <= count($splitContents)) {
    $Price=$splitContents[$counter++]
    $Percent_change=$splitContents[$counter++]
    $Company_Name=$splitContents[$counter++]
    $Company_Code=$splitContents[$counter++]
    $Volume=$splitContents[$counter++]
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your codeigniter class, you should call the **[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** function with specified url:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('url here');
```

Now you have data of specified url in `$contents` variable that you can manipulate as you like.

Comment: thank you for your help! but i dont know how I can extract the data and save into the  database.. any idea Mr. SArfraz?